# ConcurrentStack performance C++ VS Boost VS C#

Tags: c#, c++, boost, concurrency, stack

I've been trying to beat C#'s ConcurrentStack implementation in terms of performance with several different implementations including the Boost lockfree stack, and couldn't even come close.

With the test code below Boost comes in at ~4.6s, my own best performing code which is using DCAS (InterlockedCompareExchange128) on x64 at ~3.7s, C# destroys them both with a time of ~2.3s. My compiler is MSVC, full optimizations.

```
#include "boost/lockfree/stack.hpp" void TestPerformanceConcurrentStackBOOST() {
System::Diagnostics::Stopwatch sw = new System::Diagnostics::Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
int numThreads = 1;
boost::lockfree::stack<int> stack(128);

for (int t = 0; t < numThreads; t++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        for (int q = 0; q < 100; q++) {
            stack.push(q);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            int res;
            stack.pop(res);
        }
    }
}

sw.Stop();
Console::WriteLine((long)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); }
```

The C# test code:

```
        public static void TestPerformanceConcurrentStack() {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        int numThreads = 1;
        System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentStack<int> stack = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentStack<int>();
        System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Threading.ManualResetEvent> lstthreads = new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Threading.ManualResetEvent>();


        for (int t = 0; t < numThreads; t++) {
            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent mre = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((a) => {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                    for (int q = 0; q < 100; q++) {
                        stack.Push(q);
                    }
                    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                        int res;
                        stack.TryPop(out (res));
                    }
                }
                mre.Set();
            });
            lstthreads.Add(mre);
        }
        for (int t = 0; t < numThreads; t++) {
            lstthreads[t].WaitOne();
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine((long)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

I'm reasonable sure it's not just bc of C#'s garbage collection since I also tested a C++ version with custom GC, without luck. I've checked the C# code and it's pretty straightforward, not much special going on. Performance profiling showed the Boost version spends ~60% of the time in the pop method, similar to my DCAS implementation.

Does anyone have a C++ concurrent stack that's faster than C# or do you have any suggestions on what I can try next to make this faster?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: C# compiles to IL, have you checked the IL code that's compiled? there may have tons of optimizations that you don't see reading the plain C# source.

Comment: How do you build the C++ code? Did you remember to build with strong optimizations enabled? Have you tried to check the generated assembly code for the C++ example, and try to compare against the IL code generated by C#? Also note that the IL executioner does JIT of the IL code, and can use statistics of previous iterations of the loop (and maybe even of previous runs) to improve the JIT code generated.

Comment: Where is your threading on the C++ example?

Comment: Regarding the code you show, since `numThreads` is `1` in your examples, you could simplify the examples by simply not having that variable or the outer `numThreads` loop. The simpler your code is, the easier it is to understand, and the easier it is for the compilers to "understand" it as well, and to possible improve optimizations. Especially the C# code, since then you could skip the whole threading bit and make it truly equivalent to the C++ code (which it isn't now).

Comment: I removed the threading from the C++ code while trying to make it faster, I should've done the same for the C# version, sorry for that. Don't think it matters much though, even with the (slight) threading overhead C# is faster.  I'm compiling the C++ with /O2 /Ob2 /Oi /Ot /Oy /GT /GL options.

Comment: @Some programmer dude The C++ is actually native code, not managed. I implemented that stopwatch myself. Is there any way to see the jited machine code C# is executing?

Comment: Just because a solution is bad in single thread absolutely doesn't mean its bad in multithreading.

Comment: @Surt In this case it is, you'll find C# ConcurrentStack outperforms the Boost stack (or any C++ concurrent stack I tried) also in a multithreaded setup. In fact it's even worse since the odds of the (D)CAS failing increases with the procedure taking more time. Also it's not uncommon to create and initialize your container with elements from a single thread, so the test is fair.